# Change Password not working Cakephp 3.0.3

Tags: cakephp, authentication, passwords, cakephp-3.0

i am using cakephp 3.0.3, i am writing action to change user password,
for that i want to compare current password (entered by user) with existing one in database.
but it give me different hash every time,

Here is my setter for password in User Entity,

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

in controller,

```
public function changePassword()
{
    $this->request->data['current_password'] = '123456';

    $user = $this->Users->get(5); //get entity of userId 5
    $existing = $user->password; //display password of user 5 from database

    $user->password = $this->request->data['current_password'];
    $new = $user->password;
}
```

Output:

```
'$2y$10$inROlYu/ZKfowe.tTfX48OQ1q4oQBIzq3khzH5.jjITYjAxE3eMtm' //output of $existing, which is 123456 in plain
'$2y$10$A8zHGjCs/G1mlbfpzb6oIuc7TgjqC0ExR6X79kjt.1r64GSTSjpXy' //output of $new
```

here both password are same but i got diff. hash each time when i press F5 (refresh the page).

so is there any way to compare both password and change it by new one in cakephp 3.0.3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Cake uses `bcrypt` as its default hashing function. `bcrypt` does not always generate the same hash for the same input string, so you can't check it by "rehashing" a password.

Instead, use the [`DefaultPasswordHasher::check()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php#L66) method instead. This will properly compare `bcrypt` passwords for you.

```
$verify = (new DefaultPasswordHasher)
  ->check($this->request->data['current_password'], $user->password);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($this->request->data['current_password']);
```

You need to get hash for current password too.